# Calculating 3D point from Essential Matrix (backprojection 2D to 3D)

Tags: python, math, matrix, camera, vision

I'm trying to calculate 3D point from 2 Images. However I'm not sure whether my Implementation/thought process is correct, because I don't really know which of my calculated 3D points/Rotation & Translation matrix is the correct one.

Things which I can provide or have done:

- got the intrinsic parameters of both cameras `k1` and `k2`
- calculated the fundamental matrix with `cv2.findFundamentalMat` (fairly sure that it is correct, because i checked it with the equation  x'*F*x = 0)

```py
k1 = np.array([[512,   0, 512.],
 [  0, 512, 384],
 [  0,   0,   1]]).reshape(3,3)

k2 =np.array([[512,   0, 512.],
 [  0, 512, 384],
 [  0,   0,   1]]).reshape(3,3)

fMatrix = np.array([[ 2.13503670e-06, -1.09093289e-05,  1.34791051e-03],
 [ 1.15140270e-05, -8.93292052e-07, -8.31221024e-03],
 [-4.24200928e-03,  7.99815714e-03,  1.00000000e+00]]).reshape(3,3)

p1 = np.array([752, 573,   1])
p2 = np.array([701, 542,   1])
print(p2.T.dot(fMatrix).dot(p2))
```

```
-0.015196065125415714
```

- calculated the essential matrix `E = K2.T * F *K1` (Not sure if this is correct)
- extracted the rotation and translation Matrix `R`, `R2` and `Sb`, `S2b`.
- constructed the 4 possible extrinsic matricies `M1`,`M2`, `M3`, `M4`, with [R|t]

```py
essentialMatrix = k2.T.dot(fMatrix).dot(k1)
U, S, V = np.linalg.svd(essentialMatrix)

newEssentialMatrix = U.dot(np.diag([1,1,0])).dot(V.T)

U, S, V = np.linalg.svd(newEssentialMatrix)

W = np.array([[0, -1, 0], [1, 0, 0],[0, 0, 1]]).reshape(3,3)
Z = np.array([[0,1,0],[-1,0,0],[0,0,0]]).reshape(3,3)

Sb = U.dot(Z).dot(U.T) # [t]x
R = U.dot(W).dot(V.T) # R
S2b = U.dot(Z.T).dot(U.T) # [t]x
R2 = U.dot(W.T).dot(V.T) # R

t1 = np.array([[Sb[2][1]],[Sb[0][2]],[Sb[1][0]]])
t2 = np.array([[S2b[2][1]],[S2b[0][2]],[S2b[1][0]]])

# M = [U W.T V.T | t] = # M = [U W.T V.T | t] = [R | t]
M1 = np.append(R, t1, axis=1) 
M2 = np.append(R, t2, axis=1)
M3 = np.append(R2, t1, axis=1)
M4 = np.append(R2, t2, axis=1)
```

- trying to verify which extrinic/projection Matrix I need to use. In other words I'm creating for camera1 the projection matrix `P1 = k1*[I|0]`.
- And for camera2 4 different projection Matricies `P2 = k2*M1`, `P2 = k2*M2`, `P2 = k2*M3`, `P2 = k2*M4`
- Testing\calculating with a the corresponding points `p1` and `p2` and  `cv2.triangulatePoints()`

```py
    origin = np.array([[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0]]).reshape(3,4)
    projectionM1 = k1.dot(origin)
    
    projectionM2 = k2.dot(M1)
    p3D = cv2.triangulatePoints(projectionM1,projectionM2,p1[:2],p2[:2])
    print("M1")
    print(p3D/p3D[3])
    print("-----")
    projectionM2 = k2.dot(M2)
    p3D = cv2.triangulatePoints(projectionM1,projectionM2,p1[:2],p2[:2])
    print("M2")
    print(p3D/p3D[3])
    print("-----")
    projectionM2 = k2.dot(M3)
    p3D = cv2.triangulatePoints(projectionM1,projectionM2,p1[:2],p2[:2])
    print("M3")
    print(p3D/p3D[3])
    print("-----")
    projectionM2 = k2.dot(M4)
    p3D = cv2.triangulatePoints(projectionM1,projectionM2,p1[:2],p2[:2])
    print("M4")
    print(p3D/p3D[3])
```

So here are my results:

```py
    M1
    [[-0.19115383]
     [-0.12595232]
     [-0.51133412]
     [ 1.        ]]
    -----
    M2
    [[0.19115383]
     [0.12595232]
     [0.51133412]
     [1.        ]]
    -----
    M3
    [[-0.6098932 ]
     [-0.25755958]
     [-1.29386456]
     [ 1.        ]]
    -----
    M4
    [[0.6098932 ]
     [0.25755958]
     [1.29386456]
     [1.        ]]
```

So my question is which one is the correct one?
My guess it's either M2 or M4 since they only contain positive Z values, but then again, I have no idea how the coordinate system of camera1 is defined, maybe M1 or M3 might be correct.
In [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2kNy.png) you can see the perspective of camera1 with the point which should be calculated.

If anything else is missing or wrong pls don't hesitate to tell me. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Are there not an infinite number of possible solutions here?

Comment: @MadPhysicist There are only for possible solutions arcording the method. I don't know the full details myself but after making sure, that the corresponding points lie on the same plane as the real 3D point and after obtaining the projection matricies we use triangulation (don't know how it works in full detail) to form rays from both corresponding points. And since they all lie on the same plane the must intersect.
You may refer [here](http://vision.psych.umn.edu/users/schrater/schrater_lab/courses/CompVis07/Papers/Stereo.pdf) scroll to the slide "Extract t and R from the Essential
Matrix"

Comment: And my problem is I don't know how to prove which of the matricies are correct.